# ResultSet contains no rows?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I am firing the following query.

```
SELECT
    A.FIRST_NAME AS EMP_FIRST_NAME,
    A.LAST_NAME AS EMP_LAST_NAME, 
    A.EMAIL_ID AS EMP_EMAIL_ID,
    A.EMPLOYEE_TYPE AS EMP_EMPLOYEE_TYPE,
    A.SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS AS EMP_SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS, 
    B.FIRST_NAME AS HR_FIRST_NAME,
    B.LAST_NAME AS HR_LAST_NAME,
    B.FAX_NUMBER AS HR_FAX_NUMBER,  
    B.EMAIL_ID AS HR_EMAIL_ID 
FROM
    HR_EMPLOYEE A ,
    HR_REP B
WHERE
    A.HR_REP= B.REP_ID
    AND 
    A.USER_ID='FOSTER'
```

When I fire this in Java using

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

I am supposed to get exactly one row.

So I do this

```
if(rs.next())
{
  rs.getString("xxx");
  rs.getString("yyy");
}
```

but `rs.next()` always return false, indicating no rows have been fetched.

I copy the same query and run in Oracle's Editor I get the output.

So the query is correct. Why is this happening?

See output in Oracle

[image]

**Note:**

When I fire a single table query i.e no join the `rs.next()` returns true.
I have worked in Java for a long time but have never ever come across such an issue. Please help.

**Update:**

Full code:

```
@Component
@Service
public class GeneralUserImp implements GeneralUserService{

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Reference
    ConnectionProvider connectionProvider;

    public Employee getEmployee(String userId) throws Exception{
        Connection connection=null;
        Statement statement=null;
        ResultSet resultSet= null;

        try{
            connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
            log.info("****************** connection ::>> "+connection);

            statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            log.info("****************** statement ::>> "+statement);

            String query = "SELECT A.FIRST_NAME AS EMP_FIRST_NAME,A.LAST_NAME AS EMP_LAST_NAME, A.EMAIL_ID AS EMP_EMAIL_ID,A.EMPLOYEE_TYPE AS EMP_EMPLOYEE_TYPE,A.SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS AS EMP_SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS," + 
                " B.FIRST_NAME AS HR_FIRST_NAME,B.LAST_NAME AS HR_LAST_NAME,B.FAX_NUMBER AS HR_FAX_NUMBER,  B.EMAIL_ID AS HR_EMAIL_ID"+
                " FROM HR_EMPLOYEE A ,HR_REP B WHERE  A.HR_REP= B.REP_ID AND A.USER_ID='FOSTER'"; // This doesn't work 

            //String query = "SELECT SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS FROM HR_EMPLOYEE  WHERE  USER_ID='"+userId+"'"; this works

            log.info("The Query ::"+query);
            resultSet   = statement.executeQuery(query);

        log.info("****************************************) ");         


            if(resultSet.next())
            {
                log.info("-------------------FINE-----------------------------");
                Employee employee= new Employee();              
                employee.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("EMP_FIRST_NAME"));
                employee.setLastName(resultSet.getString("EMP_LAST_NAME"));
                employee.setUserId(resultSet.getString("USER_ID"));
                employee.setSpecialInstructions(resultSet.getString("SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS"));
                employee.setEmailId(resultSet.getString("EMP_EMAIL_ID"));
                employee.setEmployeeType(resultSet.getInt("EMP_EMPLOYEE_TYPE"));
                employee.setOfferLetter(null);
                employee.setNonCompeteLetter(null); // Need to be changed later
                employee.setSpecialInstructions(resultSet.getString("EMP_SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS"));

                HRRepresentative representative = new HRRepresentative();
                representative.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("HR_FIRST_NAME"));
                representative.setLastName(resultSet.getString("HR_LAST_NAME"));
                representative.setEmailId(resultSet.getString("HR_EMAIL_ID"));
                representative.setFaxNumber(resultSet.getString("HR_FAX_NUMBER"));

                employee.setHrRepresentative(representative);

                return employee;

            }
            log.info("---------------Nothing in ResultSet------------------------------------");
            return null;


        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            log.info("---------------Catch ---------------------------------");
            log.error("VideoJet Exception::", exception );
            throw exception;
        }
        finally
        {
            log.info("--------------------FINAKLYY----------------------------");
            DatabaseUtils.closeConnections(connection, statement, resultSet);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you share the full java code (especially the part containing the query itself)?

Comment: If the query is correct, then the logic place to look is a problem with the connection.  Are you connected to the right server?  To the right database?  Does the connection have permissions on the table you want to read?

Comment: Yes sir I am connected to the right database with the right credentials.. All other service and controllers use the same connection provider and are working fine.
Also if I fire non-join query I get a resultSet that is not empty.
The problem occurs with multiple table queries ...!!

Comment: try using an inner join in the from clause ? something like FROM
    HR_EMPLOYEE A join HR_REP B on A.HR_REP = B.REP_ID

Comment: Actually I don't have very strong knowledge about joins. One thing that bothers me is I copy paste this same query in Oracle and it runs fine. Then why is Java's ResultSet giving problems? I'll try the inner join . I would appreciate if you can help me with the innner Join.

Comment: use what i posted above, then change the where clause to WHERE A.USER_ID='FOSTER'   i don't know that that's the problem, just trying things at this point.

Comment: If you are really running exactly the same query against the same DB/schema, is all the data in "Oracle's Editor" committed? Or have you maybe just inserted something that fulfills the join condition?

Comment: Yes I am sure My Query is fine. Iv'e been stuck on it for 3 hours now.. I must have checked it 1000 times.

Comment: @Nathen Hughes -Inner join doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the mistake. @Sanjeev you are wrong. I fired joins in updatable resultssets it worked.

This is my mistake actualy

I had modifed B.REP_ID using toad's editor but I did  not commit. So when I fired the query in editor it showed the modified result (BUT STILL Data was not commited). but when I fired query using Java JDBC it showed doesnot exists as I had not commited. When I committed the actualy  databse got reflected and then I fired java querty(JDBC) it worked.

anayways what we learn is 
**BUT You can fire multiple join queries in UPdatable statment in Java.!!** 
@Sanjeev what you said applies to pretty old JDBC specification.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your **ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE**

As per resultset limitation from oracle

> To produce an updatable result set:
>
> A query can select from only a single table and cannot contain any
>   join operations.

[Please see For more information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/resltse2.htm) Section: **Result Set Limitations and Downgrade Rules**

You can remove that flag to proceed.

Comment: Sounds great but doesn't work.
Before this I have used an updatable resultSet for a join and I have succeded. This is the query That one of my other Service Classes fire and it works fine.

`resultSet   = statement.executeQuery("SELECT A.USER_ID ,A.FIRST_NAME AS EMP_FIRST_NAME,A.LAST_NAME AS EMP_LAST_NAME,"+ 
     "B.FIRST_NAME AS HR_FIRST_NAME,B.LAST_NAME AS HR_LAST_NAME, A.EMAIL_ID as EMP_EMAIL_ID," +
   " A.EMPLOYEE_TYPE as EMP_EMPLOYEE_TYPE FROM HR_EMPLOYEE A ,HR_REP B WHERE  A.HR_REP= B.REP_ID AND A.EMPLOYEE_TYPE != 4");`